# How to bring a node to the front in vis.js?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I need to bring the selected node to the front in a vis.js network and also z-index other nodes. Same like D3 force layout, refer [link](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3146). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you to read through this thread: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3146

Comment: Yakovl, thank you for your response. But I can't get an idea from this thread. Could you please guide on this.

Comment: Well, before I go into details, please describe what exactly you would like to achieve. "bring the selected node to the front" – this is done automatically, isn't it? If not in your case, please provide an example of code that reproduces the issue. "also z-index other nodes" – ?? Do you mean that you'd like to put on top all the nodes connected with the selected one? If so, what order should they have if they overlap themselves?

Comment: Similar to this [D3 force layout highlight node](https://bl.ocks.org/almsuarez/4333a12d2531d6c1f6f22b74f2c57102). But when I click the node and connected edges and it will  be highlighted to the front and other nodes will be fade out